# Only certain countries can access particular route

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

I am using `nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)` on an `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS` machine.

I have a `laravel project` and `phpmyadmin` running.

My `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example-application` file looks like the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name http://78.46.214.238/;
    root /var/www/demo_laravel_nlg-generation/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    # phpMyAdmin:
    location /phpmyadmin {
        root /usr/share;
        index index.php;
    }
    # PHP files for phpMyAdmin:
    location ~ ^/phpmyadmin(.+\.php)$ {
        root /usr/share;
        index index.php;
        #fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

To secure my web phpmyadmin interface I was thinking to block certain countries or even regions or allow only specific IPs from accessing my `\phpmyadmin` route, however my web applications should still be accessible for everyone.

Any suggestions how to do this in my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example-application` file?

I really appreciate your replies!

Comment: How about [*not* installing phpMyAdmin](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/security/stop-installing-phpmyadmin) for security reasons? Any modern MySQL GUI client will do much better and easier to install on your desktop.

Comment: I doubt phpMyAdmin is at all needed at the web hosting. It might be useful on the dev machine, but certainly it's a huge hole in the security with absolutely no useful gain for the production environment. Everything you might need to do there is to import/export SQL which is better to do using console `mysql` and `mysqldump` tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow just add this to your `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example-application`

```
allow   allowed.public.ip.here;
deny    all;
```

`allowed.public.ip.here` can be change to a IP (an example `1.1.1.1`) or  subnets IP class(an example `1.1.0.0/16` to block IP range from 1.1.0.0 to 1.1.255.255). an example:

```
location ~ ^/phpmyadmin(.+\.php)$ {
    allow   1.1.0.0/16;
    deny    all;
    root /usr/share;
    index index.php;
    #fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
```

To block certain countries, you need [GeoIp module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geoip_module.html). But I don't recommend it because affect the performance on low spec server. But if you want just install the Geo IP DB  on your Ubuntu using below command;

```
apt-get install geoip-database libgeoip1
```

and then add this to your config:

```
geoip_country /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;
map $geoip_country_code $allow_visit {
   default yes;
   US no;
   CA no;
}
```

above example is to block US n Canada.

To block region/continent you can use new DB of GeoIP, you can [follow these steps](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-by-geoip/) but I didn't test it yet